# Merge two lists in python to one

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to merge two list onto one list and print it

for example:

```
list1 = [9, 3, 5, 7]
list2 = [5, 4 , 6]

list3 = [9, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I need to do it with "for" or "while" because we haven't learn something more advanced than that.

my code for now:

```
list1 = [3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [1, 2, 0, 9, 9]
tlist = []
n1 = len(list1)
n2 = len(list2)
n3 = n1 + n2
n4 = len(list2) - 1
n5 = len(list1) - 1
i = 1
c = 0
while i in range(0, n3):
    tlist.insert(i, list1[c])
    tlist.insert(i, list2[c])    
    c += 1
    i += 2
tlist.extend(list2[n4:])
tlist.extend(list1[n5:])
for num in tlist:
    print num
```

the result is:

```
3
1
4
2
5
0
6
9
9
6
```

(thats how it is supposed to be in the end)
so I've manage to do it if len(list1) = len(list2)
but if the list are in different length it's not working

Comment: either you should first write one list then the other or check in your loop whether any of the lists have been exhausted

Comment: Do you need just any merge, or do you need to maintain the interleaving you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code always appends the last element of each list, regardless of the list lengths.  Instead, try this extension:

```
tlist.extend(list2[c+1:])
tlist.extend(list1[c+1:])
```

I get the expected output with this change: it starts from where the loop left off (c), instead of from the last element (n4, n5).

Also, your while loop bound is wrong; it works only if the two list lengths differ by no more than 1.  Otherwise, you'll get a subscript out of range error.  Try this:

```
for c in range(min(n1, n2)):
    tlist.insert(i, list1[c])
    tlist.insert(i, list2[c])
    i += 2
    # do not increment c; the for statement handles that part.
```

This quits the copying when either list runs out.

By the way, *please* change to meaningful variable names.  The n1-n5 series tells us nothing about their purposes.  'c' and 'i' are also weak.  Don't be afraid to type more.

---

Updated program, including lengthened test case:

```
list1 = [3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [1, 2, 0, 9, 8, 7, -1]
tlist = []
n1 = len(list1)
n2 = len(list2)
n4 = len(list2) - 1
n5 = len(list1) - 1
i = 1

for c in range(min(n1, n2)):
    tlist.insert(i, list1[c])
    tlist.insert(i, list2[c])
    i += 2
    print tlist

tlist.extend(list2[c+1:])
tlist.extend(list1[c+1:])

print tlist
```

Comment: Okay i tried that one but im still getting index error when i add more numbers to one of the list. and about the variables when im have a finished code

Comment: Okay ... so post the current state of the program and the result you got?  You did this well on the original posting, but you have to keep it up.  To help speed things up, I'll add what I think the program should be now.

Comment: thank you, i tried your code and its exactly what i need, but can you explain the loop you've made?

Comment: (1) What did you miss in your code that it didn't work (learning experience)?  (2) I don't want to over-explain: what did you not understand when you looked up Python's _for_, _min_, and _range_ ?

Comment: i think the loop wasnt built well, its my first time that i use loop and i took my a while to understand how to use it properly. i didnt understand the range(min part. when i tried to put other ranges of all sorts it still didn't  worked when the loop wasn't the same length.

Comment: That's why you need the "min" function to give the correct stopping point.

Answer (score 0):

simply add two lists using "+" to merge them.

```
In [1]: a = [1,2,3]

In [2]: b = [2,3]

In [3]: a+b
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

or you can do the following:

```
for i in b:
   ...:     a.append(i)
   ...:     

In [5]: a
Out[5]: [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

Comment: if you look at my exemples, the new list need to be: list3 = [list1[0], list2[0], list1[1], list2[1]...